# Spring boot doFilter not sending request to route on public server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am creating REST API  using Spring boot.

I have middleware that parses JWT token.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class MiddleWareAuth implements Filter {

/**
 * insance of TokenMangaer
 */
private TokenManager jwt;
/**
 * insance of UseDao
 */
private UserDAO userDAO;

/**
 * Constructor for class
 */
public MiddleWareAuth(){}
@Autowired
public MiddleWareAuth( TokenManager jwt, UserDAO userDAO ) {
    this.jwt = jwt;
    this.userDAO = userDAO;
}

@Override
public void destroy() {}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

/**
 * Function for parsing token.
 *
 * @param request ServletRequest
 * @param response ServletResponse
 * @param chain FilterChain
 */
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String xHeader = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getHeader("Authorization");
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
    System.out.println("--> " + path);
    String requestMethod = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod();

    if(requestMethod.equals("OPTIONS")){
        System.out.println("OK OPTIONS");
        res.setStatus(200);
        return;
    }

    if(path.contains("/user/login") || path.contains("/user/register")  || requestMethod.contains("OPTIONS") ||
            path.contains("/home/") || path.contains("/faq/getGlobal") || path.contains("/favicon.ico")) {
        chain.doFilter(request,response);
        return;
    }

    int id;
    try {
        System.out.println(xHeader);
        id = jwt.authToken(xHeader);
        UserEntity user = userDAO.getUserById(id);
        if( id == -1 || user.getIsAdmin() == -1 ) {
            res.setStatus( 501 );
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("SOM ID " + id );
        if( path.contains( "/admin/" ) ) {
            if( user.getIsAdmin() != 1 ) {
                res.setStatus( 501 );
                System.out.println( "No admin" );
                return;
            }
        }
        request.setAttribute("userId", id );
        chain.doFilter( request , response);
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(MiddleWareAuth.class.getName()).log( Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        res.setStatus(404);
    }
}
```

}

doFilter just parses JWT token. Every request adds Authorization header that contains JWT token.

What my problem is, that the request is send from client, doFilter process it, but `chain.doFilter( request , response);` does not send it to the controller but instead it probably sends it to same doFilter ( in same class ) again, with difference that `jwt` is null now...

This behaviour happens only on public server, Apache tomcat ( catallina.sh ). On localhost it works fine.

What could cause this behaviour and how could i fix it?
Thanks for help.